# Is there a Thundercats movie in production?

Tags: thundercats

I saw a trailer on YouTube for **Thundercats: The Movie** starring Vin Diesel and Hugh Jackman.

**Is this a fake trailer? Even if it is, will get to see a real movie soon?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Probably not

The trailer you are referencing is [fan-made](http://www.kpopstarz.com/articles/237032/20150901/thundercats-movie-2016.htm), and not an official trailer for a *Thundercats* movie. As James McAvoy says, while talking about how he would like to play Lion-O:

> "I would love to see a Thundercats movie but it's never going to
>   happen," McAvoy revealed in an interview. "Lion-O is something great
>   for any actor out there" In the said fan made trailer, actors Hugh
>   Jackman, Vin Diesel and Brad Pitt were seen in the clip which got him
>   really excited and hoping for an announcement in 2016 for a possible
>   "Thundercats" movie. "There is a great trailer for Thundercats where
>   they took Brad Pitt and made him Lion-O, Hugh Jackman as Tygra and Vin
>   Diesel as Panthro," the 35-year-old actor said.

There [may have been plans](http://variety.com/2007/digital/markets-festivals/o-flaherty-to-direct-thundercats-1117973736/) for a CGI movie, but those were [abandoned long ago](http://www.slashfilm.com/footage-abandoned-cgi-thundercats-movie/).

In addition, there is some evidence that rumors of a live-action movie were an [April Fools joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/363at4/what_ever_happened_to_the_live_action_thundercats/).

The trailer is not real, and there isn't really any reason to think a *Thundercats* movie is in production, whether animated or live-action.

Comment: i love thundercats..if thy made a movie also superb..

Comment: Who is this "McAvoy" person?

Comment: @Richard James McAvoy, talking about how he would like to have a role in a *Thundercats* movie.

Comment: @Jonah - Is there a specific reason this individual would have any special knowledge of whether the film is in production?

Comment: @Richard - No, the quote is simply there to show that the *trailer* is fanmade, which is the gist of the question (until you changed it for some reason).

Comment: @Jonah - I changed it to widen the question. There's no point ending up with two questions on the same subject (*a) Is this trailer real? b) Everyone said this trailer wasn't real, so is there a real film in production?*) when they can be easily combined

Comment: @Richard - Well, twice the reputation for me is a good reason. :) But I added information indicating that no live action film is planned.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know you are talking about [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fb50GMmY5nk). You should know that it's a fan made so again, not a real one.
But it's not that there is no such a possibility of [Thundercats movie](https://www.facebook.com/ComikazeExpo/photos/a.169949746381025.38784.154424564600210/1124333604275963/?type=3) (again a rumour as stated by Stan Lee's Comikaze Expo's facebook page).
A live action movie would be good, but again, it depends on the director(to be), actors and the franchise.